# Hacer un bloqueo de un cron

Tags: php, ubuntu, curl, crontab, cron

a ver si alguien me hecha una mano, tengo un cron que me genera un feed de productos en 26 idiomas, y ya me empieza a pasar que aveces da timeout se me ha ocurrido dividir el el archivo en 3 en lugar de tener script.php tener script1.php script2.php script3.php y lanzar el cron a script 1 pero que el 2 no empiece hasta que termine el 1 para que no se machaquen, seria algo asi

```
51 01 * * * curl -IH 'Host: mydomain.com' -H 'SSL-ON: on' http://127.0.0.1/script1.php
51 01 * * * curl -IH 'Host: mydomain.com' -H 'SSL-ON: on' http://127.0.0.1/script2.php
51 01 * * * curl -IH 'Host: mydomain.com' -H 'SSL-ON: on' http://127.0.0.1/script2.php
```

otra opcion es dejar un espacio de tiempo considerable entre ellos, pero no se si es la mejor opción, alguien sabe del tema?

Answer (score 1):

Se me ocurre esta opción:

```
51 01 * * * curl --max-time 1200 -IH 'Host: mydomain.com' -H 'SSL-ON: on' http://127.0.0.1/script1.php
```

Donde la opción `--max-time` define en segundos el tiempo que tiene que pasar para que ocurra el *timeout*. Te he puesto en el ejemplo 1200 segundos (20 minutos), pero puedes ajustarlo a lo que consideres oportuno

Answer (score 0):

¿y que tal si unes todo dentro un único megacomando con `&`?

```
51 01 * * * curl -IH 'Host: mydomain.com' -H 'SSL-ON: on' http://127.0.0.1/script1.php & curl -IH 'Host: mydomain.com' -H 'SSL-ON: on' http://127.0.0.1/script2.php & curl -IH 'Host: mydomain.com' -H 'SSL-ON: on' http://127.0.0.1/script3.php
```

así se ejecutaría todo de manera secuencial. O si quieres algo más ordenado, crea un sheel script con los comandos, digamos `scripts.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
curl -IH 'Host: mydomain.com' -H 'SSL-ON: on' http://127.0.0.1/script1.php
curl -IH 'Host: mydomain.com' -H 'SSL-ON: on' http://127.0.0.1/script2.php
curl -IH 'Host: mydomain.com' -H 'SSL-ON: on' http://127.0.0.1/script3.php
```

luego das permiso de ejecución con `chmod +x scripts.sh` y agregas a tu crontab con:

```
51 01 * * * /larutadondeeste/scripts.sh
```